# Control is not redirected to Payment page after trail period exceeds

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have raise `RecurringApplicationCharge` for my app. I set `5 days trail` period and for test purpose i include `"test":true`.

I install app in a test store

After completed  `5 days` trail my app is still active . it doesnot return to the payment page.

**How can i handle this ? . shall i do any thing manually?**

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding things. The merchant has agreed to install your App. That means they agreed to allow your App access to scopes and perhaps a charge. Once installed, the trial is nothing more than a buffer of days before Shopify starts charging them money.

In other words, when the trial ends, nothing changes except the customer begins being charged money... It is not like the trial stops the App from working. If you wanted that, you'd have to roll your own trial system.